# Windows batch - match folders with a dot (.) in the folder name

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to figure out how to match folders with a dot in the file name (e.g., ".svn") in a Windows batch script.

Here's the basic script:

```
setlocal
pushd c:\myDir
@echo off
FOR /D /r %%G in ("*\.whatever") DO (
    echo %%G
    REM do stuff
)
@echo on
popd
endlocal
```

This works just fine for most folder names (e.g., `"*bin"`), but I can't figure out the method to specify a folder with the dot. `"*.whatever"` and `"*\.whatever"` return no results. I'm guessing I'm missing some escape character or something equally simple, but I haven't been able to find any documentation on it.

(Before anyone asks, no I'm not trying to recursively delete subversion folders; `"*.svn"` is just an example.)

Comment: Discovered that the real problem was that the folders I was looking for were hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something, but as you say it seems simple

```dos
for /r /d %%a in (.*) do echo %%~fa
```

But if the folders are hidden, the normal `for` will not be able to see them, so we need to execute a `dir` command an process its output with a `for /f`

```dos
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /ad /s /b .*') do echo %%~fa
```

Comment: Of course it is. I just discovered that my real problem is that someone decided to mark the specific directories I want as hidden. If I'd tried looking for something else (.settings for example), I would've realized the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Ickster, my fault, this is a usual case and I didn't think on it. Answer updated. How to handle the case of hidden folders included.